# comboBoxSelectionDidChange gives me previously selected value

Tags: macos, notifications, nscombobox

I am using this notification for NSComboBox. Only problem is when I select a different item in the dropdown it always show previously selected value in the combo box. How can I get the currently selected value. I need to make some controls enable/disable based on the value.

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSComboBox *comboBox = (NSComboBox *)[notification object];

        NSLog(@"[comboBox stringValue] : %@", [salaryBy stringValue] );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the selected value using:

```
NSString *strValue = [comboBox itemObjectValueAtIndex:[comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]];
```

Comment: That is weird. This is an Apple bug

Comment: ```extension NSComboBox
{
    func selectedStringValue() -> String?
    {
        return self.itemObjectValue(at: self.indexOfSelectedItem) as? String
    }
}```

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed this bug and fixed it in a different way. The correct value can be fetched when we read the value in the next run of the main run loop after the comboBoxSelectionDidChange method call as shown below

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{ 

    [self performSelector:@selector(readComboValue:) withObject:[notification object] afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)readComboValue:(id)object
{
   NSString *comboValue = [(NSComboBox *)object stringValue];
   NSLog(@"%@", comboValue);
}
```

produces the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I use these code with success!

Setting up:

```
@interface YourWindowController : NSWindowController<NSComboBoxDelegate,NSComboBoxDataSource>


- (void)windowDidLoad
{

comboBox.usesDataSource = YES;
comboBox.datasource = self;
comboBox.delegate = self;
[comboBox selectItemAtIndex:0];

}


-(void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{

NSLog(@"Selection = %@ ",[[array objectAtIndex: (long)[comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]] objectForKey:@"yourkey"]);



}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the NSComboBox `selectionDidChange` notification is not well documented and its actual meaning is easily misunderstood.

The notification does **not** mean that the field value has changed, or even that it will change, it merely means that a menu item was *selected*. In particular, when using keyboard navigation, the notification is triggered when using the up/down arrow keys to move through the menu but the text in the field won't actually change unless you press enter (which does not trigger a notification).

This means that attempting to use this notification by getting the object value of the selected item (as shown by @Adion) can actually result in unexpected behaviour as it doesn't necessarily reflect the field value. Using a delay to get the field value instead (as shown by @SayeedHussain) can avoid this but it won't pick up the change if applied with the enter key.

Unfortunately I haven't yet found a nice way of properly detecting changes to the combo box - as far as I know the only solution is bindings/KVO.

One possibility is forcing the menu item to be applied as soon as it's selected (`comboBox.objectValue = comboBox.objectValueOfSelectedItem`), but that's a change of standard UI behaviour and may not be desirable.