# NSComboBoxDelegate called but old 'stringValue' remains

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

I select a value from the drop-down of a combo box. The NSComboBox delegate fires a comboBoxSelectionDidChange: notification, but when I retrieve the stringValue of the combo box, it's the old selected value.  How do I get the updated value?

I have a dataSource specified, so `itemObjectValueAtIndex:` and `objectValueOfSelectedItem` don't work.

Comment: I'm retrieving via [comboBox stringValue];

Comment: @Bavarious: objectValueOfSelectedItem won't work since I'm using a dataSource.  Exception thrown: ` *** -[NSComboBoxCell objectValueOfSelectedItem] should not be called when usesDataSource is set to YES `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using a data source, then:

```
NSString *s = [yourDataSource comboBox:comboBox
             objectValueForItemAtIndex:[comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]];
```

should work if your data source provides strings. Otherwise, convert the object returned by this method to a string.

Comment: Whats this in Swift? I seem to keep getting a crash?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265260/comboboxselectiondidchange-gives-me-previously-selected-value):

> I got the selected value using:

```
NSString *strValue = [comboBox itemObjectValueAtIndex:[comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]];
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Exception thrown: `*** -[NSComboBoxCell itemObjectValueAtIndex:] should not be called when usesDataSource is set to YES`